# POP3 authentication using email address in Exchange

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, pop3

I'm running an Exchange 2010 server. I need to allow POP3 authentication using an email address as the user ID instead of the domain username. Here's an example:

> AD Domain: domain.local
>   Email domain: domain.com
>   Username: johndoe
>   email address: j.doe@domain.com
>
> John logs into his computer using the username johndoe@domain.local but has an email address that is j.doe@domain.com. Can I enable POP3 authentication using the email address rather than the UPN? How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, looks like the answer is that there is no answer. There is no way to do this. Exchange will only authenticate using domain username.

Comment: I know that to be the case with Exchange 2003, and based on your post it looks like it's the same with Exchange 2010. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

mapi-labs will do this as long as you setup the addittional email in the email settings in AD>> user>> username.
pretty straightforward really